# The query returns values before inserting data

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I have a rating table.

```
CREATE TABLE merchants_rating(
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id     INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
    merchant_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
    rating      INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

I want to insert data into it and get the sum of the seller’s rating and the number of users who rated it.

I made a request.

```
WITH INSERT_ROW AS (
  INSERT INTO MERCHANTS_RATING (USER_ID, MERCHANT_ID, RATING) 
  VALUES(147, 92, 2)
)
SELECT SUM(R.RATING) AS SUMMA_RATING, COUNT(R.USER_ID) AS USER_COUNT 
FROM MERCHANTS_RATING AS R 
WHERE R.MERCHANT_ID = 92
```

The data is added successfully, but there are problems in the output. When the table is empty and the first time I add data to it, I get such values.

```
 SUMMA_RATING | USER_COUNT | 
----------------------------
     NULL     |     0      |
```

Although I expect to receive.

```
 SUMMA_RATING | USER_COUNT | 
----------------------------
      2      |      1      |
```

Since one user has rated the seller.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), so **they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Luckily the manual also explains how to work around that:

> This [...] means that RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between different WITH sub-statements and the main query

You need to use a UNION between the existing rows and the inserted rows:

```
WITH insert_row AS (
  INSERT INTO merchants_rating (user_id, merchant_id, rating) 
  VALUES (147, 92, 2)
  returning * --<< return the inserted row to the outer query
)
SELECT sum(r.rating) AS summa_rating, count(r.user_id) AS user_count 
FROM (
  SELECT rating, user_id
  FROM merchants_rating
  WHERE merchant_id = (SELECT merchant_id FROM insert_row)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rating, user_id
  FROM insert_row
) r;
```

If you intend to insert more than row in the first step, you need to change the `r.merchant_id =` to `r.merchant_id IN`

Online example: https://rextester.com/BSCI15298

Comment: A simple insert, and select sum will do without these too many lines of codes

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ absolutely true, I was just trying to address the original question

Comment: `r.merchant_id=92` will make cte useless in this answer.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ: there is no `r.merchant_id=92` in my answer

Comment: I get an error `ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias LINE 7: FROM(`. How to do it all right for me?

Comment: Did you copy the `) r` part?

Comment: i also tried this query, and its not working. @megaRoks, why this answer is accepted?

Comment: Because I got an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your are trying to do.

> 1. insert some values to `merchants_rating` from `insert_row`  cte.
> 2. select sum and count from table `merchants_rating`

```
insert into merchants_rating (user_id, merchant_id, rating) 
with insert_row as ( 
  select 147, 92, 2 
) select * from insert_row;

select sum(rating) AS summa_rating, count(user_id) AS user_count 
from merchants_rating where merchant_id = 92;
```

See [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6a1d9/1/0)

Comment: The common table expression (`WITH`)  is pretty useless in this example